# Adding a seed to my program (Word Letter Scramble)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble figuring out how to add a seed to my program. It is supposed to be able take a given seed value and return a scrambled sentence. The first and last letters in a words should stay the same as well as ending punctuation. Any punctuation within a word is allowed to be scrambled.

```
import random
import string

original_text = input("Enter your text: ").split(' ')
seed = int(input("Enter a seed (0 for random): "))
if seed is not 0:
    random.seed(seed)

randomized_list = []

def scramble_word(word):
    alpha = word[0]
    if word[-1] == "," or "." or "!" or "?" or ":" or ";":
        omega = word[-2] 
        middle = word[1:-2]
    else:
        omega = word[-1]
        middle = word[1:-1]
    reorders_text = random.sample(middle, len(middle))
    shuffled_text = "".join(reorders_text)
    new_words = alpha + shuffled_text + omega
    return new_words
for item in original_text:
    if len(item) <= 3:
        randomized_list.append(item)
    else:
        randomized_list.append(scramble_word(item))
new_words = " ".join(randomized_list)
print(new_words)
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a seed to the program, with 0 being a random seed, you would need to call `random.seed()` to your program as so:

```
seed = int(input("Enter a seed (0 for random): "))
if seed is not 0:  
    random.seed(seed)
```

Pretty simple.

See the Python docs for more info: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html

In the future, it is always worth turning to the documentation before posting here. For basic things like this, the docs will probably answer your question.

Comment: Do I need to reference the seed when I randomize my middle characters? Also do you have any suggestions on how I can make the last letter of a word followed by punctuation stay the same.

Comment: Ex) Hello! should scramble as Hlelo! or Hlleo! but not Holle!

Comment: You could add an else clause

`else:
    random.seed()
`

Comment: You don't have to reference the seed again. `random.seed()` initialises the generator with a given seed. Play around in an interactive terminal if you're not sure how it will behave.

Comment: You would need to check whether the next item in the list is punctuation, and if it is, then don't include the last letter in the shuffle. Many different ways to implement that. Try and figure it out, and come back if you have a specific issue.

Comment: I edited my program, but now it does not bring punctuation and some letters of words. Any further suggestions?

Comment: You might be better off posting a new question with a very specific problem, and what you have tried to do to fix it. Also, editing the original question to include the answer just confuses things. Anyone searching in the future will wonder what your original question was.